# Написал программу которая считает сигму, но при запуске всегда выдает 0. c code

Tags: c

[image: уравнение]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()  {
  int n,i,j;
  float s,p;
  s=0;p=1.0;
  printf("\n Input n=");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      p=p*(j+cos(j));
    }
    s=(2i*(sin(i)+1)/p);
  }
  printf("\n Rezult=%f",s);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Вот код который у меня получился. Но к сожалению он не работает. Прошу подскажите в чём дело.

Comment: К сожалению, у Вас в коде неаккуратно расставлены отступы.

Comment: Суммирование! `s += (2*i*....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что Вы запускаете старую версию программы, так как код в вопросе не скомпилируется.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  
  p = 1;
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {  
    p = p * (j + cos(j));  
  }  
  s = s + 2 * i * (sin(i) + 1) / p;  
}
```